# const auto reference binding to (null) pointer - what is the actual type?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++17, auto

While looking into some code, I came across a construct with the following line:

```
if (const auto& foo = std::get_if<MyType>(&bar)) // note the ampersand!
```

where `bar` is a `std::variant<MyType, OtherType>`. The problem here is that `get_if` [may return a null pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) and I don't understand why the statement works.

Consider this similar MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { int a = 42; };

Foo* f() { return nullptr; }

int main() {
    const auto& foo = f();          // Returns a nullptr that binds to Foo*& - UB?
    //static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo), const Foo*&>::value); // -> Fails
    //const Foo*& bar = f(); // -> Fails

    if (foo)    std::cout << foo->a << std::endl;
    else        std::cout << "nullpointer" << std::endl;
}
```

The first line of `main()` works fine, and I would expect the type of `bar`to be `const Foo*&`, but the static assertion fails. Unsurprisingly, the following line also fails to compile with `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'const Foo*&' to an rvalue of type 'const Foo*'`.

What happens in the first statement of `main`? Is this UB or does the standard contain some hidden secret that allows this to be legal? What is the type of `bar`?

Comment: The possible null-ness of the pointer's value is irrelevant - a null pointer to `T` has the same type as all other pointers to `T`. `nullptr` is not a pointer but an object that can be implicitly converted to any type's null pointer. Its type is `nullptr_t`.

Comment: `get_if` cannot return `nullptr` (which is a value of class type `nullptr_t`).  It must return a pointer value, which can be a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the note @M.M. Then I assume the reference is somethat misleading as it explicitely states for the return value: _"Pointer to the value stored in the pointed-to variant or **null pointer** on error. "_? In any case, it seems that I need to update my knowledge on null pointers.

Comment: @andreee "null pointer" is a possible value for a pointer. `nullptr` is not a null pointer (and not a pointer at all); it's an expression that can be implicitly converted to a null pointer of any type.

Comment: @M.M I'm a little bit confused. If `get_if` returns a pointer value which can be a null pointer, what do you get if not a `nullptr` (which, as you said, is of type `nullptr_t`)?

Comment: @andreee I don't understand your confusion sorry. You seem to indicate you understand that `nullptr` is not a null pointer, and you understand what `get_if` returns, but then you ask "what do you get" anyway?

Comment: @M.M I think I've got it in the meantime... I think I mixed up a couple of things on my way, but now I'm there I guess. I've read some sections in the standard and reference and now it seems clear to me. Thanks a lot for your comment, I would never had thought that I had a completely wrong idea of null pointers all the time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that for `const auto& foo`, `const` is qualified on the `auto` part, i.e. the pointer but not the pointee. Then the type of `foo` would be `Foo* const &`, which is a **reference to `const`** (pointer to non-`const` `Foo`), but not `const Foo* &`, which is a **reference to non-`const`** (pointer to `const` `Foo`).

And the lvalue-reference to `const` could bind to rvalue returned by `f()`, so `const auto& foo = f();` works fine; `const Foo*& bar = f();` won't work because `bar` is an lvalue-reference to non-`const`; which can't bind to rvalue. Changing the type of `bar` to `const Foo * const &` or `Foo* const &` (same as `foo`) would make it work.

Comment: When dealing with variable-pointer-to-const vs const-pointer-to-variable, I find it convenient to consistently put the `const` to the *right* of the thing it is qualifying (and not use the extension that if there is no type to the right, it qualifies the type to the left).  Thus `foo` is `Foo* const &`, not `Foo const* &`

Comment: @MartinBonner East-const 4 lyfe!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have references to the standard by any chance? Wasn't able to find them myself (at least not to for that particular case)...

Comment: @andreee You want the reference for which part? Yes it's not easy to find the straightforward statement in the standard, especially for the 1st paragraph of my answer..

Comment: First part would be great... I'm unable to find the exact rules in the standard or reference. The second part is covered [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue): _"An rvalue may be used to initialize a const lvalue reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends. "_ and _"An rvalue may be used to initialize an rvalue reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends. "_ - perhaps you could add that?

Comment: @andreee Precisely it has nothing to do with `nullptr`, what `something_returning_nullptr()` returns is always a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) despite of the function returns a `nullptr` or not. *"a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is non-reference, such as `str.substr(1, 2)`, `str1 + str2`, or `it++`;"*